# Stringstream to string return?

Tags: c++, stringstream

So I have to write a .dot file to make a graphviz image of a sorted avl tree. Method header was provided and I have to make do with it.

Main question is how do I call the build_dot_content() method properly when it is part of std::string?

```
void avl::dump_dot(std::string filename){
  string s;
  ofstream fptr;
  fptr.open(filename);
  fptr<<"digraph AVL {"<<endl<<"graph [dpi=150];"<<endl<<"nodsep=0.3;"<<endl;
  fptr<<"ranksep=0.2;"<<endl<<"margin=0.1"<<endl<<"node [shape = circle fontname=\"Helvetica\"];"<<endl;
  fptr<<"edge [arrowsize=0.8]"<<endl<<endl;
  stringstream o;

  s=string build_dot_content(o, root, 1);
  fptr<<s<<endl<<"}"<<endl;

}

std::string build_dot_content(std::stringstream &o, avl_node *e, int i) {
  o<<"node"<<i<<" [label =\""<<e->element<<"\"];"<<endl;
  int iL = 2*i;
  int iR = 2*i+1;

  if(e->left != nullptr){
    o<<"node"<<i<<" -> node"<<iL<<";"<<endl;
    build_dot_content(o, e->left, iL);
  }
  if(e->right != nullptr){
    o<<"node"<<i<<" -> node"<<iR<<";"<<endl;
    build_dot_content(o, e->right, iR);
  }
  string s;
  s = o.str();
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Please expand on or reword "Main question is how do I call the build_dot_content() method properly when it is part of std::string?" Currently I cannot make much sense of it.

Comment: this is the error that I'm getting. 

avl.cpp:216: undefined reference to `avl::build_dot_content(std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, avl_node*, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Sorry for the nitpicking but `fptr`? File pointer? Huh? `fstream` != `FILE*`. It's not a pointer, it's a stream object.

Comment: please do, I think I've had some bad teachers not explain the basics very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break this function up into two;

1. Main function which is called with the node and `i`
2. A second function which streams out the node only

Call the second function from the first with the root node, and in that function recursively call itself to stream out the tree. At the end of the main function, generate the string from the stream and return it..

-- Alternatively

You dump function already has a stream, pass this to the `build_dot_content` function along with the node and index, and this can recursively stream out the elements - it should not return the string...

Comment: Sadly I have to do it with the given headers, TA required the functions to be used as defined

Comment: you can't change the signatures? then go with the latter approach, just ignore the return value and return a blank string, frankly it's a stupid signature.. it should be `void build_dot_content(std::ostream& o ...)` this will allow you to then propagate the file stream directly ...

Comment: Yeah i'm not sure why he had it as an std:string method, switching to void worked perfectly. Thanks.